# Vicious cycle: No DPKG & No space left on device

Tags: 18.04, dpkg

Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS on GCP

```
df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root      3870720 158973 3711747    5% /
devtmpfs       1923380    387 1922993    1% /dev
tmpfs          1924177      1 1924176    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1924177    554 1923623    1% /run
tmpfs          1924177      8 1924169    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1924177     18 1924159    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       12823  12823       0  100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop1       23213  23213       0  100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/86
/dev/loop2       12820  12820       0  100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/sda15           0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop3       23074  23074       0  100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/88
tmpfs          1924177     10 1924167    1% /run/user/1001
```

Trying to do anything with the boot partition, such as

```
ls -l
>>>...
>>>cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/file/magic.mgc' to '/usr/lib/file/magic.mgc.
dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
```

Broken partition

```
sudo apt-get remove  linux-headers-4.15.0-1036-gcp   
>>>E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct th
e problem.
```

Same when trying

```
sudo apt remove p7zip-full
```

No space to fix the broken partition !

```
sudo dpkg --configure
>>>dpkg: error: failed to write status database record about 'libstdc++6:amd64' to '/var/l
ib/dpkg/status': No space left on device$
```

Comment: Some of your detail is confusing (does `ls -l` really get a *No space left on device* error?)  Did you install server? or desktop?  How much space did you allocate (the desktop recommends 25gb, but you may need more if you ...) or server? If you didn't allocate enough space, you may need to manually remove (or `mv`) files to get enough space to allow package tools to work..

Comment: CLI Server. Not enough space is the problem

Comment: I still don't see any detail about your space, only inodes.  As I've already suggested why not `rm` or `mv` files (with move I meant to another partition/system so it may involved a `scp` then `rm`) creating the space so you can use package tools. Allocate more space (this can be real easy or not-so-easy depending on your system & setup).  I've also in the past moved system directories to other partitions to fix space issues, but if you are asking for help it's probably right for you; keep it simple (& safe).